# Negative Effective Resistance

Tags: resistance, negative-resistance

Assume that we have a circuit that is connected with components that have positive resistance. At this point the effective resistance between every two node is positive. (below is an example of such circuit)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC5HsF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, if we add components with negative resistance, we can have negative effective resistance between two nodes. (Here the effective resistance between node 1 and node 3, has become -2).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foDami.png)</sup>
At this point, is it possible to make the effective resistance between every two nodes positive by adding more negative resistance components?

Comment: "negative" resistance is not a real world phenomenon to my knowledge...

Comment: negative resistance does exist, see tunneling diodes, and it got Esaki a Nobel prize.  it's relative to operating conditions.  the posters question is not really clear

Comment: @vicatcu Even if you think it doesn't exist, think of it as an abstract element.
@ b degnan, where is the ambiguity?

Comment: Please make this question clearer, potentially with a pseudo-circuit diagram. You can use the circuit diagram tool in the editor, and remember to use text labels liberally to refer to node points etc

Comment: Of course, negative resistances do exist - and are widely used in practice (filters, oscillators). There are various realization methods - but always on the basis of active componenets (transistors, opamps). Negative resistances are nothing else than voltage controlled current sources with the current going through the controlling voltage source.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a loop with a mixture of positive and negative resistance, provided that the overall sum is positive or negative.  In either case, in the absence of an external current source or sink, the voltage at all points in the loop will be equal, which will in turn imply that the current must be zero.  If there were a loop where the sum of positive and negative resistances totaled zero, then it would be possible for an arbitrary amount of current to flow around the loop, creating potential differences at nodes around the loop.

Comment: here my question is not about current and voltage (yes they have equal voltage here). My question is with a circuit in which equivalent resistance between some nodes are negative, can we plug some negative resistance between nodes in order to have positive "equivalent resistance" between all nodes?

Comment: @user114313: If you can add negative resistance components in series with positive ones, you can reduce the positive resistance.  If positive and negative resistances with different magnitudes are in parallel, the sign of the result will be that of the smaller resistance.

Comment: @supercat: You're right that if the total resistance is strictly positive and there are no non-proportional sources (a negative resistance is a proportional dependent source), the current will converge to zero.  But for strictly negative total resistance this will not happen.  Sure, it is the only solution to the system, but it isn't a stable equilibrium -- any noise disturbing the system will produce positive feedback in the dependent sources and current will "run away" until limited by some non-linear effect.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Good catch, and one I should have recognized, since IR-compensation systems that are compensated to negative net resistance end up behaving that way.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thinking about it a little more, in the absence of any inductance or capacitance in the loop, could any non-equilibrium condition be created by externally-attached devices in a way that would persist when they were disconnected?  A positive resistance loop will be stable even in the presence of inductance or capacitance, while any non-zero capacitance or inductance will facilitate a runaway condition, but I can't think of any way to set up the runaway condition in ideal negative resistors by temporarily connecting external stimuli.  Is that possible?

Comment: @supercat: That concept doesn't really make sense.  An "ideal" negative resistor is infinitely fast to respond, so the "temporary connection" of an external component is relatively infinite -- this stimulus should actually be treated as a part of the loop but with an initial condition.  If you add any capacitor or inductor carrying non-zero energy to the loop, you'll get the runaway, and there will be no delay between connection of the charged element and the runaway.  e.g. if the stimulus is switched in at \$t=0\$, the circuit already lacks any finite solution at \$t=0^+\$.

Comment: Any loop containing series capacitance or inductance must have positive resistance for convergence, but if one had a loop with ideal negative resistance and momentarily connected ideal voltage and/or current sources, or inductors and/or capacitors with sufficient series resistance to avoid creating any negative-resistance loops, I don't know how one could force any instability in the negative ideal-resistance loops.

Comment: For example, if one has two vertically-oriented -1ohm resistors in parallel with each other, and momentarily connects a one volt supply in parallel with the combination (positive on top), then while the supply is connected, there would be 1amp flowing upward through each resistor.  Instantaneously cutting the supply would cause the currents through the resistors to cease; how could it do otherwise?

Comment: The resistors would immediately change the amount of voltage they drop to balance the loop currents, which would imply that the voltage and current would both be zero